# Login with SSL activated with cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, https

I have activate ssl with my app and everything is going well... well, exept login. It is impossible to login to my app. Here is my form code that used to work with nude http :

```
  <div class="users form">
    <div class="form-login-box">
      <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
      <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
        'class' => 'form-login',
        'inputDefaults' => array(
          'label' => false
         )
      )); ?>
      <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
          'class' => 'form-login-username',
          'placeholder' => __('Login')
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
          'class' => 'form-login-password',
          'placeholder' => __('Password')
        ));
        ?>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('Login') ?>" class="form-login-submit">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my controller :

```
  public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array('class' => 'authMessage-error'), 'auth');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: And what is the error you’re getting?

Comment: No error. Just no logged

Comment: Any idea ? I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Have you actually looked into CakePHP’s error log in **app/tmp/errors/error.log**?

Comment: It's empty, no error logged.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to login? Does it redirect anywhere or show anything on the screen? What if you try echo-ing or die-ing in various places in the controller code to see where it gets to? Also, the flash message won't show until you redirect, so it may simply be failing login but you can't see it.

Comment: The page loads, but then nothing happens sc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your not actually closing the form the Cake way. Try this.

Replace the

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo __('Login') ?>" class="form-login-submit">
```

With

```
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit'); ?>
```